# Creating protected cross reference page number links in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Good Day

I have a large document where I need to refer to some page numbers of specific text on whatever pages they may be. I need to give this document to users, and I want to make it as "fool proof" as possible, by "protecting" the referenced page numbers from being deleted/edited.

My solution was to create rich text control fields, bookmark the field, and cross reference to the bookmark and insert the cross reference as a page number.

So, in more clear steps:

- *Developer > Controls > Rich Text Control*
- Change the properties to be *"Content control cannot be deleted"* and *"Content   Control cannot be edited"*
- Create a bookmark to the field
- Insert the cross reference as a page number where I want the page number to be.

Now, this does give me the page number I want and makes sure the text is always there, but a user is still able to delete the cross reference. So, I put the reference in a Rich Text Control field as well, but the user will still be able to delete the cross reference.

When Word creates cross references to bookmarks as text (which were created in the same way), it inserts the reference as protected and non editable, just like the bookmarked "source" - is there something similar I can use to protect the page numbers?

Kind Regards

Comment: What version of Word are you using? If I stick a cross-ref field (page #) in a Rich Text Control in Word 2016, and turn on its Content control cannot be edited and Content control cannot be deleted settings, I can't edit (update) or delete that reference after I exit Design Mode. Are you making sure that you exit Design Mode?

Comment: Hi @cnread, I'm using Word 2016. I want to be able to create a field that only contains the reference, without being able to delete the reference, or add any text to the field. So, enabling all the content controls gives me that option, but now I can't update the page number if the page should change. I should also point out that I only enabled all the Content control on the "Bookmarked" text, not the referenced page number.

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to update the page #s yourself if you turn on Cannot edit for the content controls. What I'd do is turn on just the Cannot delete setting for those content controls, and then lock the cross-ref fields by selecting all and then pressing Ctrl+F11. That way, if you ever have to update the page #s, you can select all, unlock fields (Ctrl+Shift+F11), update (F9), and then relock (Ctrl+F11). (Otherwise, you'd have to unlock each content control individually.) This won't prevent people from adding text to the content control; they just won't be able to update the field itself.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @cnread. I have found a way of always keeping the reference in the field, without locking the cross-ref fields. (I simply selected the entire field, and then typed the pageref. Now, even if you delete all the text within the field, the cross-ref remains and the number comes back automatically.) But it would have been nice to have that field locked for editing, but not updating as well.